# Making an image on an windows-authentication site public

Tags: asp.net, image, windows-authentication

Is it possible to make an image in an ASP.NET site that uses Windows Authentication, publicaly accessible (i.e. without asking users to login)?

**EDIT**

Sorry for not updating this earlier. I figured out eventually that you could apply anonymous access on a single file/image in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also have anonymous authentication enabled, and the NTFS permissions on the images allow Everyone group Read access, then they should display without prompting for login.